# php $_GET issue - updated

Tags: php, get

thanks now I have a error code HY093 Invalid parameter number after using the renameit SUBMIT button. Any idea why? thanks

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
<?php 
// init
include("db_con1.php");
require("menu.php");

// modify distribution list name
if(is_numeric($_GET['gid'])) {
  $g_id=$_GET['gid'];
  $one = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM contactgroups WHERE id=:gid');
  $one->bindParam(':gid', $g_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  if( $one->execute(array(':gid' => $_GET['gid'])) ) {
   $result = $one->fetch();
  }
}

// distribution list query
$queryl = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, gr_name FROM contactgroups WHERE status=1 ORDER BY gr_name ASC');
$queryl->execute();

// Members list query
if (isset($_GET['gid'])) {
  $g_id=$_GET['gid'];
  $querym = $pdo->prepare('SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN gm.linktype, if( gm.linktype = "group", cg.gr_name, cm.contact_sur ) mname FROM groupmembers gm LEFT JOIN contactgroups cg ON gm.link_id = cg.id LEFT JOIN contactmain cm ON gm.link_id = cm.id WHERE gm.group_id =:gid ORDER BY mname ASC');
  $querym->bindParam(':gid', $g_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $querym->execute();
}

// distribution list query
$queryr = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM contactmain WHERE status=1 ORDER BY contact_sur ASC');
$queryr->execute();
```

This is what should but does not work...

```
if (isset($_POST['renameit'])) {
    $ren = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rename']);
    $g_id = $_GET['gid'];

    if ($g_id !== '' && is_numeric($g_id)) { // Change that first to == if gid != 0 as well
        $sqlren = "UPDATE contactgroups SET gr_name = :rename WHERE id = :gid";
        $sqlren = $pdo->prepare($sqlren);

        $sqlren->bindValue(':rname', $ren); // <<< Is this supposed to be :ren?
        $sqlren->bindValue(':gid', $g_id);

        if ($sqlren->execute()) {
            echo  "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=groups.php\">";
        } else {
            //Query failed.
            $errorcode = $sqlren->errorCode();
            echo $errorcode;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'gid not provided'; // Or something
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the HTML bit:

```
<form id="group-in" method="post" action="groups.php">
Add new Distribution group: <input type="text" name="newgroup" placeholder="name...">  <input type="submit" name="createit" value="Create new">
Rename groupname: <input type="text" name="rename" value="<?php echo $result['gr_name']; ?>"> <input type="submit" name="renameit" value="Rename">
</form>

<!-- Distribution list  -->
<div id="left"><label class="header">Distribution list</label>
<ul>

 <?php foreach ($queryl as $i => $rowl) { ?>

  <li >
   <?php if ($i)?>
   <input name="checkbox1_add[]" id="dist_<?php echo $i ?>" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rowl['id']; ?>" />
   <label for="groups_<?php echo $i ?>">
   <a href="groups.php?gid=<?php echo $rowl['id']; ?>" <?php $g_id=$_GET['gid']; if ($g_id==$rowl['id']) echo 'class="bold"'; ?> >
    <?php echo $rowl['gr_name']; ?>
   </a></label>
 </li>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

sorry for the long code but I think I loose this $_GET somehow after selecting the distribution item.

Comment: You're using prepared statements, but don't use placeholders and directly insert _GET values? Talk about being so high up on the "secure" scale you've blown past +infinite and come back in at -infinity.

Comment: dude, you need to give a simplified example. no one wants to read that much code for what appears to be a trivial error.

Comment: thanks I know Marc, because I reduced the code as I can't get the gid anyway. When I find the glitch I will change it to secure. As I said I even can't echo it... if you have a good idea please let me know.

Comment: @regality thank for your comment I am going to shrink it

Comment: @regality I have shrink it down however it is still not short, but I think too many part can go wrong...

Comment: You still have an error in your PDO statement; it says `:rename` but your `bindValue` is `:rname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing something like this?

```
if (isset($_POST['renameit'])) {
    $ren = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rename']);
    $g_id = $_GET['gid'];

    if ($g_id !== '' && is_numeric($g_id)) { // Change that first to == if gid != 0 as well
        $sqlren = "UPDATE contactgroups SET gr_name = :ren WHERE id = :gid";
        $sqlren = $pdo->prepare($sqlren);

        $sqlren->bindValue(':rname', $ren); // <<< Is this supposed to be :ren?
        $sqlren->bindValue(':gid', $g_id);

        if ($sqlren->execute()) {
            echo  "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=groups.php\">";
        } else {
            //Query failed.
            $errorcode = $sqlren->errorCode();
            echo $errorcode;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'gid not provided'; // Or something
    }
}
```

Also, if it's always going to be an integer, you could use:

```
$g_id = (int)$_GET['gid'];
```

But you would need to be careful with things that evaluate to `0` and check for it in your `if` statement:

```
if ($g_id > 0) {
```

Assuming `0` is not a valid `gid` value.

**EDIT**

Looking at your markup and form, this all seems confused.

For instance, your PHP code is using `GET`, but your code here is not including the `gid` in the `ACTION` attribute. (Also, you really should use two different forms for this, IMO.)

```
<form id="group-in" method="post" action="groups.php?gid=<?php echo $g_id;?>">
 Add new Distribution group: 
 <input type="text" name="newgroup" placeholder="name...">
 <input type="submit" name="createit" value="Create new">
</form>
<form id="group-in" method="post" action="groups.php?gid=<?php echo $g_id;?>">
 Rename groupname: 
 <input type="text" name="rename" value="<?php echo $result['gr_name']; ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="renameit" value="Rename">
</form>
```

However, your comment seems to suggest that multiple checkboxes can be checked to rename a group? But then you don't have a `FORM` tag around it:

```
<!-- Distribution list  -->
<div id="left"><label class="header">Distribution list</label>
<form id="group-in" method="post" action="groups.php">
<ul>

 <?php foreach ($queryl as $i => $rowl) { ?>

  <li >
   <?php if ($i)?>
   <input name="checkbox1_add[]" id="dist_<?php echo $i ?>" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rowl['id']; ?>" />
   <label for="groups_<?php echo $i ?>">
   <a href="groups.php?gid=<?php echo $rowl['id']; ?>" <?php $g_id=$_GET['gid']; if ($g_id==$rowl['id']) echo 'class="bold"'; ?> >
    <?php echo $rowl['gr_name']; ?>
   </a></label>
 </li>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>
</form>
</div>
```

The challenge that you're going to have here is that you need to loop through that `$_POST['gid']` array, whereas the first single group rename you key off of the `gid` in the `GET`. I would suggest organizing your code into a `Group`/`Groups` object(s) and use a Model/View/Controller (MVC) pattern to organize your code.

Comment: Thanks very much the indeed!!! Your code works, however the gid still does not come on even /ad-minok/groups.php?gid=1 this is in the to bar. I think the $_GET['gid'] is an array??? but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: No, it's not an array. If you put `exit($g_id);` in there right after the variable is created, you don't see a value (`1` in this case)?

Comment: Note also the comment about the apparent conflict in the `rname` and `ren` statement value identifiers. It looks as if they should match.

Comment: This is how the html look like  I just can't see what is wrong with it... <li >
            <input name="checkbox1_add[]" id="dist_0" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      <label for="groups_0">
      <a href="groups.php?gid=1" class="bold" >
        St C Trustee      </a></label>
    </li>

Comment: If that were the case and that was a `FORM` that has a `method="GET"` attribute, then your URL would not be `?gid=1`, it would be `?gid[]=1&amp;gid[]=4`, etc..., for each value that was selected and submitted. You would have to loop through those, even if only value was checked.

Comment: thanks now I have a error code HY093 Invalid parameter number - any help on that, or ideal? thanks

Comment: Your code and markup seems very confused. See my edit. You should consider using a different, more organized approach, like an MVC framework (CodeIgniter is a good one).

Comment: many thanks for your comment and kind help I am a beginner and I am still learning how to do things.

Comment: You are RIGHT! the gid is not an array as only one field to rename at the time. At the action bit I have tried to pass the gid: your code works however I am still getting HY093 and the SQL still stays as it is.

Comment: That error is because your PDO value identifier does not match your `bindValue` call. Look real close; I also left a comment under the question about this, too.

Comment: thank you very much!!! Yes as I confused the computer I did confused myself as well. So many things together added the issue. Thanks again I am going to star this as I've learned a lot from you thanks again.

Comment: The best thing to do is to slow down, think everything through, and keep it as simple as possible. Programming/scripting is a detail-driven activity that is very stepwise in nature, so getting in a hurry is counter-productive to learning. Really, take a look at [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com); might as well learn a solid approach to start with. :)

Comment: I reposted that last comment since I had some egregious errors in my grammatical syntax. Just remember to keep it simple and to focus on each step.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you can't get `$_GET['gid']` after you submit the `group-in` form?

Because if that's the case, what you have to do is create a hidden input with your `gid` value so it can be available in `$_POST`.

Without putting much thought to what you're trying to do, I can tell you that you simply can't have code using `$_GET` and `$_POST` simultaneously.

**Update:** I don't think you understood what I meant. But Jared is already doing a better job explaining what is wrong with your code, so I guess I won't repeat it.

Comment: agree a bit of mishmash my code, but without AJAX I could not pass info on so I used GET but where I could I used POST to hide stuff.